# Make one json object a child of the other using java

Tags: java, json

I'm working out a problem, and this part of it I could use some assistance on, I have the following JSON array:

```
parentArray: [{"name":"folder1","children":[],"parent":"root","type":"folder"},        {"name":"folder2","children":[],"parent":"folder1","type":"folder"}]
```

I need to create a method that will put the put the object with name 'folder2' in to the 'children' array of 'folder1'.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Comment: Your question is way too vague. Also, the operation seems rather pointless. Use javascript instead to manipulate *parentArray* before sending it.

Comment: It's not vague really, what I'm looking to do is convert this to represent that folder2 is a child of folder1 - I'm trying to do this by parsing the two objects and then by the value in "parent" place the pertinent objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in a cleaner way using [`gson`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Create a `POJO` for `Parent` and an array value of type `Parent[]`

```
public class Parent {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(String parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Parent[] getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Parent[] children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    private String name;
    private String parent;
    private String type;
    private Parent[] children;
}
```

Easily read the json and manipulate the Parent object thus returned:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("array.json")); //File containing your initial json

Gson gson = new Gson();
Parent[] parentObjArray = gson.fromJson(br, Parent[].class);

Parent folder2 = parentObjArray[1];
parentObjArray[0].setChildren(new Parent[] { folder2 });

System.out.println(gson.toJson(parentObjArray));
```

Resulting json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "folder1",
        "parent": "root",
        "type": "folder",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "folder2",
                "parent": "folder1",
                "type": "folder",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "folder2",
        "parent": "folder1",
        "type": "folder",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

The above code uses a few assumptions specifically the exact indexes of your `json array`. You can further *generalize and manipulate* the `json` in accordance to your requirements.

Further, the 2nd element of the array can be removed to hold a single object with a child.

### EDIT:

As per your new requirement, you might want to add the files and folders too. Adopting my dirty approach I can manually set these values. However, would definitely stress on that `Files` and `Folders` can share a single data type - `Parent`, hence this solution becomes a good candidate to adopt a **recursive approach**.

So it's:

```
Folder1
      ||=> File1
      ||=> Folder2
                 ||=> File2
```

## Changed inout json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "folder1",
        "children": [],
        "parent": "root",
        "type": "folder"
    },
    {
        "name": "folder2",
        "children": [],
        "parent": "folder1",
        "type": "folder"
    },
    {
        "name": "file1",
        "parent": "folder1",
        "type": "file"
    },
    {
        "name": "file2",
        "parent": "fol‌​‌​der2",
        "type": "file"
    }
]
```

### Manually set these values and modify json

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        Parent[] parentObjArray = gson.fromJson(br, Parent[].class);

        Parent file2 = parentObjArray[3];
        parentObjArray[1].setChildren(new Parent[] { file2 });

        Parent folder2 = parentObjArray[1];
        Parent file1 = parentObjArray[2];
        parentObjArray[0].setChildren(new Parent[] { file1, folder2 });

        parentObjArray = new Parent[]{parentObjArray[0]};
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(parentObjArray));
```

### Modified json now:

```
[
    {
        "name": "folder1",
        "parent": "root",
        "type": "folder",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "file1",
                "parent": "folder1",
                "type": "file"
            },
            {
                "name": "folder2",
                "parent": "folder1",
                "type": "folder",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "file2",
                        "parent": "fol‌​‌​der2",
                        "type": "file"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Hope this gives you a better idea how your generic approach would be. Good luck!

Comment: I like this approach, as I am needing to consider further nesting for the resulting deliverable. I'll see if I can get somewhere with this one for a bit here, much thanks!

Comment: Playing around with this, it seems that 'setChildren' is not an available method (at least not in the gson dependancy I added which is 2.2.4)

Comment: @user3259647 setChildren is in the custom Parent pojo which I had posted above

Comment: OH, been going at it too long and didn't notice :S

Comment: @PoboFibo - This is really good, how would I do this with a file array that also needs to be put in to the parent objects? the array for files is like so:
[{"name":"file1","parent":"folder1","type":"file"},{"name":"file2","parent":"fol‌​der2","type":"file"}]

Comment: @user3259647 The similar way. You have to define your custom data type to hold file values, to use file depth recursively you have to have an array of File[] with the File data type (pojo if you will) (same analogy as show above with Parent - which has an array of Parent[])

Comment: @PoboFibo - I'm getting closer, I've set a File class to extend Parent, and this code is setting the folders correctly, but not the files from my file array:

 Gson gson = new Gson();
 File[] fileObjArray = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(fileArray), File[].class);
 Parent[] parentObjArray = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(parentArray), Parent[].class);
 File file1 = fileObjArray[1];
 Parent folder2 = parentObjArray[1];
 parentObjArray[0].setChildren(new Parent[] { folder2 });
 parentObjArray[1].setChildren(new Parent[] { file1 });

Comment: @user3259647 I think in that case you won't need File data type at all. Just recursively add files and folders of the same type Parent. Edited my code above with example.

Comment: @PoboFibo - Only problem I'm having now - is that the file objects in the array are the ones getting a 'children' added to them and the folders added, instead of the other way around.

Comment: @user3259647 hmm, in the above edited code I have generated the correct json with files under folders. Check that too, plus would suggest to open a new question with your attempt. It would get enough traction that way too

Comment: I had to switch around the input json, but still this is a great start to what can be a larger project for me now. Thank you a million times over!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with plain objects and then convert them to json string.

```
public class Folder {

    private String name;
    private List<Folder> children;
    private String parent;
    private String type;

    //Getter and setters

}
```

This way you can create folder from json and also write folder to json

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String temp = mapper.writeValueAsString(folderObject);
```

Comment: This could work, but I get an input that is already formatted as json so having to break that down to map it to plain objects (I think) becomes cumbersome.

Comment: Will you be validating the input or just mapping the children based on the parent names? There are chances that the folders may get mapped to wrong parents if you are not validating.

Comment: I would prefer to just map the children based on the parent name, I don't know that I need to add validation to this.

Comment: Consider this : [{"name":"folder1","children":[],"parent":"root","type":"folder"},{"name":"folder1","children":[],"parent":"folder1","type":"folder"},{"name":"folder1","children":[],"parent":"folder1","type":"folder"}]. The third folder is the child of second folder. How will you know this? As I said earlier without validation you might map the folder to wrong parents.